# Prove that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is the glb of the set $\{\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\}$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, relations, order-theory

I want to refer to Exercise 26 part (c) of Section 4.6 of Velleman's 2nd Edition book.
The exercise is as follows:

Supose $A$ is a set. If $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are partitions of $A$, then we say that $\mathcal{F}$ refines $\mathcal{G}$ iff $\forall X\in\mathcal{F} \exists Y\in\mathcal{G} (X\subseteq Y)$. Let $P$ be the set of all partitions of $A$, and let $R=\{ (\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \in P\times P \; | \; \mathcal{F} \; \text{refines} \; \mathcal{G} \}$.

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are partitions of $A$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G} = \{ Z\in\mathscr{P}(A) | Z\neq\varnothing \; \text{and} \; \exists X\in\mathcal{F}\exists Y\in\mathcal{G} (Z=X\cap Y) \}$ is the greates lower bound of the set $\{ \mathcal{F},\mathcal{G} \}$ in the partial order $R$.

My approach was the following: 1) Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds for $P_1=\{ \mathcal{F},\mathcal{G} \}$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is a lower bound; 2) Prove that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is the only lower bound.

So eventually I proved that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is a lower bound. In proving my second step I tried following this strategy: $\forall \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}$ is l.b. for $P_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}=\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$.

- Let $\mathcal{H}$ arbitrary and suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ is l.b. for $P_1$. Thus, the goal is very straightforward.
- Basically I used universal instantiation for the definition of lower bound, and I got that $(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{F})\in R$ and $(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})\in R$. I did the same but using the $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$.

This is as far as I got. It ocurred to me that I could try proving that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is symmetric so that I could use transitivity and then antisymmetry to prove that $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$, but didn't get much progress with that. I also tried proving that $\mathcal{F}\cap\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ to use that theorem that sayst that the intersection of a family of sets is the glb, but didn't go any better.

I would appreciate any hints as to how I can proceed with my strategy, or any different approach I can take for this proof.

Comment: Why do you want to prove that it is the only lower bound? Generally, it isn't. What should aim is at proving that it is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Well, yes. I mean, that is the goal of this proof. It’s just that I have been struggling with this all day yesterday, but haven’t thought of a possible approach to take

Comment: The first thing you should prove (if it hasn't been shown already) is that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is actually a partition. Otherwise you don't even know that  $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G} \in P$. for (1) you are okay, but for (2) you goal is wrong. $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is *not* the only lower bound. It is just the largest of them. I.e., you need to show that for any other lower bound $\mathcal H,  (\mathcal H, \mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}) \in R$. Showing that $\mathcal H = \mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is not necessary (and in general, not true).

Comment: @PaulSinclair it is already proven that $\mathcal{F}\cdot\mathcal{G}$ is a partition of $A$. I just cannot see how to prove the goal, since taking an arbitrary lower bound would force me to need something to plug in for the definition of $\mathcal{F}$ refines $\mathcal{G}$, but not sure what element I can use.

Comment: If $\mathcal H$ is a lower bound of $\{\mathcal F, \mathcal G\}$, then it must refine both $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$. Use that information to show that it also must refine $\mathcal F\cdot\mathcal G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ is any lower bound of $\{\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\}$. I'll denote the refinement partial order by $\le$.

Let $H \in \mathcal{H}$. It is the case that $\mathcal{H} \le \mathcal{F}$ so there exists some $F_1 \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $H \subseteq F_1$.

Also $\mathcal{H} \le \mathcal{G}$ so there is a $G_1 \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $H \subseteq G_1$.

It follows that $H \subseteq F_1 \cap G_1$ and *by definition*, $F_1 \cap G_1 \in \mathcal{F}\cdot \mathcal{G}$. As we can do this for any $H \in \mathcal{H}$ it follows that $\mathcal{H} \le \mathcal{F} \cdot \mathcal{G}$ which shows that $\mathcal{F} \cdot \mathcal{G}$ is maximal among the lower bounds of $\{\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}\}$.

So it is the glb in the refinement partial order $\le$, as claimed.

Comment: In the second line it should be $\mathcal{F}$ instead of $\mathcal{G}$. It's just a typo. But thank you very much. I was overcomplicating myself. This was actually very straightforward.

Comment: @AlejandroRuiz I edited the typo (rather copy-paste error). It's indeed quite simple, and obvious if you think about it for a while.